# SSRS MDX dataset need dynamic field source, is there a workaround?

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, dataset, field, mdx

I have a the following working MDX query. The issue lies in the TOPCOUNT where I use a case statement to work out what I am counting.

INVESTOR, ADVISER and ADVISERGROUP are all actually the same dimension linked to different fields in a fact Table, ie for Adviser it would be Entity.IDKey - > Fact.AdviserKey or for Investor its Entity.IDKey -> Fact.InvestorKey

So the problem is all will return the same field name, [ID KEY] but will have different locations ie the dataset field source definition needs to be different.

In SSRS it will only work with one case, which is the one it runs at design time, and returns incorrectly for the others.
Is there any way around this?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Previous Period] as
(   [Measures].[Fact TOL Activity Count] ,  
ParallelPeriod(
        IIF(@GroupBy = 'Y',   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year],IIF(@GroupBy = 'Q' ,  [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Quarter], [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month]))  
    , 1 
    ,[Date].[Fiscal].CurrentMember ))


MEMBER [Measures].[Current Period] as [Measures].[Fact TOL Activity Count] 

MEMBER [Measures].[CPeriod] as [Date].[Fiscal].CurrentMember.Name

MEMBER [Measures].[PPeriod] as 
ParallelPeriod(
      IIF( @GroupBy = 'Y',   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year], IIF(  @GroupBy = 'Q' ,  [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Quarter], [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month]))
    , 1 
    ,[Date].[Fiscal].CurrentMember ).Name

MEMBER [Measures].[Growth] as 

IIF (ISEMPTY([Measures].[Previous Period]), 0 , 
[Measures].[Fact TOL Activity Count]/ [Measures].[Previous Period] ), FORMAT = "Percent"


SELECT
{   
     [Measures].[Previous Period], [Measures].[Current Period],  [Measures].[Growth], [Measures].[PPeriod],[Measures].[CPeriod]

} ON COLUMNS,


(  TopCount(
    Except({

    CASE  [Dim User Type].[User Type Key].CurrentMember.NAME  
            WHEN "Adviser" THEN  [ADVISER].[ID Key].children 
            WHEN "Firm" THEN  [ADVISERGROUP].[ID Key].children
            WHEN "Investor" THEN [INVESTOR].[ID Key].children
            ELSE [INVESTMENTMANAGER].[ID Key].children 
    END

    } ,  

    CASE  [Dim User Type].[User Type Key].CurrentMember.NAME  
            WHEN "Adviser" THEN  [ADVISER].[ID Key].[Unknown]
            WHEN "Firm" THEN  [ADVISERGROUP].[ID Key].[Unknown]
            WHEN "Investor" THEN [INVESTOR].[ID Key].[Unknown]
            ELSE [INVESTMENTMANAGER].[ID Key].[Unknown]
    END
)

, 10
, (   [Measures].[Growth],  STRTOMEMBER(@CurrentPeriod, CONSTRAINED), [Dim EVENTTYPE].[IASEVENTTYPEKEY].&[ET00000040], STRTOMEMBER(@UserTypeKey, CONSTRAINED))
   )) on rows


FROM  [TOL Metrics Usage]

where  ( [Dim EVENTTYPE].[IASEVENTTYPEKEY].&[ET00000040],  STRTOMEMBER(@UserTypeKey, CONSTRAINED), STRTOMEMBER(@CurrentPeriod, CONSTRAINED) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have @UserTypeKey as a parameter. So you could base your positioning on the report based on this parameter.

You could also add another calculated member when you want to filter based on the name and you don't want to create another dataset just for the name.

```
MEMBER [Measures].[UserTypeKeyName] AS [Dim User Type].[User Type Key].CurrentMember.NAME
```